# R Shiny error "X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*, face 1 at size 9 could not be loaded"

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I am programming in R and trying to display a plot using ggplot.

But I am getting a:

> Error: X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*, face 1 at
>   size 9 could not be loaded

I am running on Ubuntu 16.04

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SUD2.png)

[image]